# Using VC++ 10 Compiler with Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, sdk

I've just installed Windows SDK 7.1. It also came with VC++ 10 Compiler but I have installed Visual Studio 2005. Does that mean i can integrate it with Visual Studio 2005 Or Do I need Visual Studio 2010 IDE?

Answer (score 1):

No, VS2010 came with SDK version 7.0A.  The installer for 7.1 should automatically make it use the version.  But I'm fairly sure that won't happen for VS2005.  I think, it's been a while since I used a machine that had it installed.  You can set the directories it searches with Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, VC++ Directories.  I wouldn't do this myself btw, not much point in installing an old version unless to maintain old projects.